# PHP, Mysql insert

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, mysql, ajax

I'm trying to make a star rating system and i can't get to insert the results into mysql. I'm missing something but I don't know what. I will show you my code, maybe one of you can see where is the issue.
Thanks in advance!

First, my form:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC '-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN' 'http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd'>
 <html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xml:lang="en" lang="en">
 <head> 
 <script src='jquery.js' type="text/javascript"></script>
 <script src='documentation/documentation.js' type="text/javascript"></script>
 <link href='documentation/documentation.css' type="text/css" rel="stylesheet"/>
 <script type="text/javaScript" src="documentation/chili/jquery.chili-2.0.js"></script> 
 <script type="text/javascript">try{ChiliBook.recipeFolder="documentation/chili/"}catch(e){}</script>
 <script src='jquery.MetaData.js' type="text/javascript" language="javascript"></script>
 <script src='jquery.rating.js' type="text/javascript" language="javascript"></script>
 <link href='jquery.rating.css' type="text/css" rel="stylesheet"/>
</head>

<body>
<div id="tab-Testing">
<script>
$('form1').submit(function() {
 var ans=$(this).serialize();
  $.ajax({
  type: "POST",
   url: "starsubmit.php",
  data:ans
 }).done(function( msg ) {
 alert( "Data Saved: " + msg );
 });
 return false;
});
</script>

<div class="Clear">&nbsp;</div>
<form id="form1">

        Question 1:bla bla bla

   <input class="star required" type="radio" name="Question 1" value="1"/>
    <input class="star" type="radio" name="Question 1" value="2"/>
    <input class="star" type="radio" name="Question 1" value="3"/>
    <input class="star" type="radio" name="Question 1" value="4"/>
    <input class="star" type="radio" name="Question 1" value="5"/>
   </div>
   <br/>
   <div class="Clear">

        Question 2:bla bla bla

    <input class="star required" type="radio" name="Question 2" value="1"/>
    <input class="star" type="radio" name="Question 2" value="2"/>
    <input class="star" type="radio" name="Question 2" value="3"/>
    <input class="star" type="radio" name="Question 2" value="4"/>
    <input class="star" type="radio" name="Question 2" value="5"/>
   </div>
   <br/>
   <div class="Clear">

        Question 3:bla bla bla

    <input class="star required" type="radio" name="Question 3" value="1"/>
    <input class="star" type="radio" name="Question 3" value="2"/>
    <input class="star" type="radio" name="Question 3" value="3"/>
    <input class="star" type="radio" name="Question 3" value="4"/>
    <input class="star" type="radio" name="Question 3" value="5"/>
   </div>
 <br>
   <div class="Clear">

        Question 4:bla bla bla

    <input class="star required" type="radio" name="Question 4" value="1" />
    <input class="star" type="radio" name="Question 4" value="2" />
    <input class="star" type="radio" name="Question 4" value="3" />
    <input class="star" type="radio" name="Question 4" value="4" />
    <input class="star" type="radio" name="Question 4" value="5" />
   </div>
   <br/>
   <div class="Clear">

        Question 5:bla bla bla

    <input class="star required" type="radio" name="Question 5" value="1"/>
    <input class="star" type="radio" name="Question 5" value="2"/>
    <input class="star" type="radio" name="Question 5" value="3"/>
    <input class="star" type="radio" name="Question 5" value="4"/>
    <input class="star" type="radio" name="Question 5" value="5"/>
   </div>
   <br/>
   <div class="Clear">

        Question 6:bla bla bla

    <input class="star required" type="radio" name="Question 6" value="1" />
    <input class="star" type="radio" name="Question 6" value="2" />
    <input class="star" type="radio" name="Question 6" value="3" />
    <input class="star" type="radio" name="Question 6" value="4" />
    <input class="star" type="radio" name="Question 6" value="5" />
   </div>

   <input type="submit" value="Submit scores!" />  </td>

</form>
</body>
</html>
```

> Now, my starsubmit.php:

```
<?php
$mysql_hostname = "localhost";
$mysql_user = "root";
$mysql_password = "";
$mysql_database = "cosmote";
$prefix = "";
$bd = mysql_connect($mysql_hostname, $mysql_user, $mysql_password) or die("Opps some thing went wrong");
mysql_select_db($mysql_database, $bd) or die("Opps some thing went wrong");
if($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"] == "POST")
{
$question1 = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['question1']);
$question2 = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['question2']);
$question3 = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['question3']);
$question4 = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['question4']);
$question5 = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['question5']);
$question6 = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['question6']);

mysql_query("INSERT INTO answers (q1,q2,q3,q4,q5,q6) VALUES ('$question1','$question2','$question3','$question4','$question5','$question6')");
echo "<h1>Thank You !</h1>";
}

?>
```

And, finally, my table:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `answers` (
  `q1` int(3) NOT NULL,
  `q2` int(3) NOT NULL,
  `q3` int(3) NOT NULL,
  `q4` int(3) NOT NULL,
  `q5` int(3) NOT NULL,
  `q6` int(3) NOT NULL
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;
```

Comment: use print_r($_POST);//to know data is post from from or not.check it out.it will print like array.

Comment: Off : http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-query.php
**Use of this extension(mysql_*) is discouraged. Instead, the MySQLi or PDO_MySQL extension should be used**

Comment: actually u need to tell us what is the error - if there is any..
and at what level or at what point your code is working fine..

Comment: **[Why shouldn't I use mysql_* function in PHP?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12859942/why-shouldnt-i-use-mysql-function-in-php)**

Comment: I can't see the error, the results are visible in browser's adress bar when i push submit, but they are not inserted in the table.

Comment: are you sure using ajax with type post giving you results in address bar of browser. Well this shouldn't be happen with type post.

Comment: Yes, results are visible in the address bar.

Comment: That is not correct. Only GET puts the parameters on the address bar, not POST.

Could you use [firebug](https://getfirebug.com/) for debugging to find where is failing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i must say this should be :

```
$('form1').submit(function() { // <------you are not submiting the specific form
```

like this:

```
$('#form1').submit(function() { // <------ every id should have a '#' in jquery
```

this might be the issue if you can change your .done function

```
.done(function() {  
   alert( "Data Saved");  // try removing the passed param "msg"
});
```

Answer (score 0):

in jQuery a ID has a "#" at the beginning

`$('form1').submit(function() {`